# AdMob: enable test ads for all devices

Tags: cocoa-touch, admob, ads

You have to specify each device for test ads:

```
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3222e18ddc56b034fdf816e0d93ee7a1", GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
```

I want to send Ad Hoc release for someone and I want him to see test ads. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in latest versions of AdMob. `BOOL testing` propery is deprecated and not working.